# Is Life after Moksha possible?

Tags: moksha, rebirth, life

Is it possible to re-enter the birth and death cycle of life after one has achieved Moksha/Nirvana ?

Comment: God says He incarnates age after age to restore Dharma isn't it. So after achieving Moksha definitely a soul can "take birth". However, the soul does not enter into the cycle of samsaar (rebirth), in the sense, the soul no longer associates itself with the body, it becomes One with all of creation and with God. Thus there is no rebirth for the 'soul' so to speak. All the best.

Comment: @Sai, can you elaborate more on how the terms "take birth" and "rebirth" are different (as both belong to *Samsaar* only)? Do you mean that after Moksha, the soul again takes its first birth? BTW, I had thought regarding your 1st sentence while answering. I *guess*, there might be some difference between supreme soul and the other (day to day) souls. God incarnates for establishing Dharma, but God doesn't get Moksha at the end of incarnation either, because being already in liberated state. I might be wrong in this case.

Comment: @iammilind Let us say Jiva X attains Liberation. It becomes merged in Divinity. Therefore from X's point of view, there is no such thing as rebirth. This is because X no longer thinks He is X. He knows that he is God. However from another jiva Y's point of view, X may take birth again for the sake of establishing Dharma. Sri Krishna in reality is neither born nor dead, everyone knows that. Sri Krishna is eternal. From Sri Krishna's point of view, He is neither born nor dead. He is God, always present! However from our point of view, he takes birth, for our sake. Similar with the saints.

Comment: @Sai completely agreed. So after liberation X = God or God = X or God + X = singularity. However Y will never encounter X's nature different than that of God.

Comment: @iammilind Y will believe X to be God incarnate (or a saint, depending on the mission of X)

Comment: @Sai, well then again there is a difference. Your last comment appears like X to be a separate God, not the supreme & singular one. Effectively I mean once X is merged into God, there is no individual form of X anymore. With respect to Y, the old X is gone forever. The only trace of X is now God. Having said this, I am confused about persond like Arjuna, who is *said to be* partly *Nara* & partly *Indra*. Such situations can be resolved by either assuming 2 souls reside in 1 body or the soul doesn't get complete Moksha. Just assumptions.

Comment: @iammilind The tricky part here is that, Y has not yet realized it. According X, whatever you said is true. But Y may still be stuck in samsaar (duality) and believe X to be a different soul. For example, there are many who believe that Sri Ramakrishna is a saint, while there are some who believe that Sri Ramakrishna is God Himself. Some others believe He is a normal man. Some believe He is a sage. So different people believe different things, based on their level of realization. But from Sri Ramakrishna's point of view, there is only one reality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No. It's not possible.**
After Moksha, a soul has become God by merging into the singularity of God. What God does, that soul does or what that soul does, the God does. Both are same.

The question rather should be,

> Is it *required* to have a life after Moksha?

A soul with no desire left and who has conquered its *Rajo-Guna* (the mode of passion) will not have anything to do with the material world. Even that soul doesn't have to guide anyone, because tendency to guide or help is also a (selfless) desire.

All the entity come to manifested from unmanifested when the day of Brahma starts. Unmanifested is the actual nature of God, which is *Nirguna* (mode-less), *Nirvikara* (distorion-less) and *Nirpeksha* (non-relative). However with its own Yoga-maya, the unmanifested God can also take a manifested form of soul, superior than the others.

Presumably, your question is about the regular souls like us. When such soul realizes the God, it finally merges within the God's unmanifested form. **It's like a water droplet merging into the ocean.**
Can we say that when a new body is formed later, the same droplet is again attached? We can safely assume that it's gone for good!

[BG 12.6, 12.7](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/12/6-7)

> But those who worship Me, giving up all their activities unto Me and
>   being devoted to Me without deviation, engaged in devotional service
>   and always meditating upon Me, having ﬁxed their minds upon Me, O son
>   of Pṛthā – for them **I am the swift deliverer from the ocean of birth
>   and death.**

[BG 13.24](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/13/24)

> One who understands this philosophy concerning material nature, the
>   living entity and the interaction of the modes of nature is sure to
>   attain liberation. He **will not take birth here again**, regardless of
>   his present position.

The souls which are going to attain Moksha would enjoy within the present life as well:

[BG 14.20](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/14/20)

> When the embodied being is able to transcend these three modes
>   associated with the material body, he can **become free from birth,
>   death**, old age and their distresses and can enjoy nectar even in
>   this life.

Comment: In those Gita verses, Krishna is just saying the soul will never be forced to take birth again once it attains Moksha.  But it can still choose to take birth on Earth, just out of compassion for the souls who are still in the cycle of birth and death.  Vyasa says in the Brahma Sutras "The released soul can animate different bodies like a lamp, for the scripture shows this to be so." http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, in the Gita verses, I don't see a *shadow* of availability of choice whether to take birth or not. They appear to be judgmental that "there won't be any re-birth post liberation". Here the keyword is **Liberation** (not *released*). You may find that text in the same link and it says: *In liberation the soul exists in a state of inseparableness from the supreme Self, for so it is noticed in the Upanishad.* That's why I gave the example of *droplet (=soul) merging into the sea (=supersoul/brahman)*. After merger any manifestation occurs, it can't associated with that droplet.

Comment: Even the Brahma Sutras say "There is no return for the released souls on the strength of the Upanishadic declaration".  Again, both Gita verse 13.24 and the Brahma Sutra statement are about forcible return - Krishna is basically saying "You're never going to find yourself being reborn all of a sudden."  But you can still go into the world if you want to.  The Brahma Sutras say that liberated souls have powers to do anything, except for interfering with the creation, preservation, and destruction of the Universe.

Comment: I think Conclusion is there is no need to reborn after moksha , But if you want than cycle of death & life available for you after Moksha am I right ?  @iammilind I think you should write this also in your answer

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola, No it's wrong. Actually Moksha is a state of "no wanting" or "nothingness". In the very link posted by Keshav, if you search "liberation", it says that the soul merges inseparably in supreme Brahman/God. In other words, soul itself become God. That's singularity or "nonseperableness". What you ask to add is already present in 1st para of answer but with different perspective. Because once soul merges to God, as  opposed to Keshav's idea, it doesn't have separate "wanting". It's inherently involved in all activities where God is involved. Droplet example is suitable for that.

Comment: "It's inherently involved in all activities where God is involved." Well, that's not quite true.  The Brahma Sutras make clear that the liberated soul acquires all powers except for the creation, preservation, and destruction of the Universe.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan you are reading my comment in bits and pieces. :-)  Since the soul has merged into god and inseparable, there is no exclusivity of that soul. May be what you talk about is pre liberation stage but not ultimate. Assuming that If the soul is still different than God, in such case 2 options exist. Either the soul hasn't attain Moksha or if that's Moksha then there is a higher situation than it.

Comment: @iammilind No, the Brahma Sutras make clear that when it is said that the liberated soul becomes equal to Brahman, it is about equality of experience only, not equality of powers.

Comment: @iammilind This may help: I assume you're an Advaitin.  Well, how Advaita conceptualizes this situation is that there are two perspectives, a relative perspective and an absolute perspective.  From the absolute perspective, the individual soul realizes that it is Brahman and that there was never a physical world to begin with, so there's no question of having any powers over the world and no question of descending into it.

Comment: @iammilind But from a relative perspective (the perspective of someone living in Maya), the physical world still exists, and the liberated soul and Brahman remain distinct entities, with Brahman having all powers over the world and the liberated soul having most powers except for creation, preservation, and destruction.  And both Brahman and liberated souls have the capacity to descend to the Earth and enter into bodies, out of compassion for the Jivas still stuck in Samsara.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, though I am not sure if I am Advaitiyan (due to my less knowledge), I feel quite in sync with the absolute perspective you described in your 2nd last comment.

Answer (score 2):

yes, soul can always enter cycle of life-death even after achieving Moksha. Have you studied Advaita Vedanta and Shudhadvaita(non-dual reality)? Human souls are nothing but fragments of the divine God, and if maya or ignorance or the instinct of I is removed from soul, soul is equivalent to God. Than what the hell caused the maya in very first place to delude divine God himself and appear in the form of infinite souls. It is avidya, that is forgetting true self. Moksha simply means established in true self(the non-dual reality). And life simply means forgetting the true self and having desire of anything other than true self. Kindly study teachings of buddha.

2) Life is permeated through suffering caused by desire, 
3) Eliminate desire and you eliminate suffering and attain moksha.

Also, study Samkhya laid out by Kapila muni, which revolves around Purush and Prakriti,

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya

The idea of evolution in Samkhya revolves around the interaction of prakṛti and Purusha. prakṛti remains unmanifested as long as the three gunas are in equilibrium. This equilibrium of the gunas is disturbed when prakṛti comes into proximity with consciousness or Purusha. The disequilibrium of the gunas triggers an evolution that leads to the manifestation of the world from an unmanifested prakṛti. Purusha is pure consciousness absolute, eternal and subject to no change. It is neither a product of evolution, nor the cause of any evolute. It is what is called the soul of every one of us.

Samkhya considers ignorance (avidyā) is regarded as the root cause of this suffering and bondage (Samsara). Samkhya offers a way out of this suffering by means of discriminative knowledge (viveka). Such knowledge, that leads to mokṣa (liberation), involves the discrimination between prakṛti (avyakta-vyakta) and puruṣa (jña)

But if later purush again forgets to discriminate between prakriti and purush(himself) when prakṛti comes into proximity with him(purusha), he will again manifest or fall in cycle of life-birth. So, only method of liberation is to always remain in introversion, that is nirvikalp samadhi or see everything with indifference

Answer (score 1):

No Soul after achieving Moksha will enter the cycle of birth and death because he is free from each and every imperfection.

But still they can come on earth to guide souls towards the kingdom of God. Just for the purpose of helping more souls realize the absolute truth, they come to earth. Though in this life they know for what purpose they are on earth, they have already risen above Maya and various imperfections. They are free.

Comment: Answers on this site should be with reliable sources, they shouldn't just be your personal opinion. So please find sources to back up your answer