# What will happen when all atmans get moksha?

Tags: moksha, vedanta, advaita, brahma-sutras, vishishtadvaita

In Vedanta philosophy, the different schools of thought like [Vishishta-Advatia](https://sa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%83), [Advaita](https://sa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%83), [Dwaita](https://sa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D) etc. agree upon the following facts:

**1. There are constant numbers of [jeevatman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiva) in the universe/Samsara** (consisting of all 14 [Lokas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka))

**2. After [Moksha](https://sa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%83), a jeevatman cannot return to any other state** (but individual can roam around if he wants to).

So looking for the future with these constraints, a time will come when all jeevatmans present in the whole creation would get [moksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Moksha&redirect=no). What would happen when such a saturation condition occurs?

The only solution I see is to again create more jeevatmans (since bramhan is all powerful and all pervading). Bramhan can pull this off, but why is he not allowed to create more of jeevatmans?

[More information on Vedanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37524/discussion-on-question-by-yogi-what-will-happen-when-all-atmans-get-moksha).

Comment: Well, as far as I know most of the Shruti and Smriti scriptures refuse the samsara after Moksha (i.e who attains Mokhsa, never returns). Your question is intelligent but (imo) attaining the absolute/ultimate truth is the only way to know all such things! (as our mind/intellect is under the influence of illusion)

Comment: @Pandya Yeah being in Moksha state is the only way to know Bramhan and have Bramhanjnana. When we have Bramhanjnana we would know everything of this Samsara and the realm beyond.

Answer (score 0):

**All Atman will definitely get Moksha and after that the whole cycle will repeat again.**

1 cycle of Brahma contains several events in *MAyA* upon *jiva*s. During its day, all the manifestation is created and during night they are annihilated and merge within the nature of *Nirguna Brahman* (i.e. Moksha). Now, I am not claiming Brahma's cycle to be just limited to day and night. It could be year or 100 years as well.
The point of interest here is **"cycle"**, which repeats.

To avoid copy pasting of all the detailed answers and scriptures, I am linking my previous answers:

1. Within the scope of Brahma's 1 cycle: The *Jiva*s or *Atman*s will
   not take the birth again. Explained in: [Is Life after
   Moksha possible?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8878/1049).
2. Within the scope of eternity, i.e. beyond Brahma's cycle. All the
   *Jiva*s would come back and repeat themselves, whatever they did earlier. So even though Moksha is quite long, it's not permanent.
   Explained in: [Is Moksha a permanent
   state?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10744/1049)

Comment: There are few questions, which are in the same league. Any discussion on this topic will be relevant to all the 3 questions. Hence if you feel any doubt or correction, kindly drop a message in **chatroom: [Everything is Predetermined yet Unknown](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36056/everything-is-predetermined-yet-unknown)**. Thanks!

Comment: @yogi - I think , Sribhasya of Swami Ramanujacharya answers such questions. Simply put there will never be a time when all the jivatmas will be liberated as the number of jeevatmas are infinite in real sense, is my little understanding. Moreover,  Supreme Para Brahman doesn't create jeevatmas. Refer to BG verse wherein Lord Krishna says that there was never a time that he ( Paramatma) didn't exist and there was never a time jeevatma ( Arjuna ) didn't exist. So, in short, jeevatmas are infinite in number and always exist as along with one and only Paramatma.

Comment: Annihilation of Jivatmas during night is not Moksha

Comment: @Pandya, according to Gita 14.2, assuming the nature of "I"(Brahman) is the state when one doesn't have to take rebirth, i.e. Moksha. From verse 9.7, during end of day or beginning of night everything assumes the nature of "I"(Brahman). These 2 verses make the foundation that everyone gets Moksha at the end of (BrahM's) day. If you have any contradictory verse then kindly present it here. If you feel that translations of these 2 verses are not right then refer which translations make you believe the opposite.