# If liberation does not lead back to bondage, how can time be cyclic?

Tags: time

Is all time cyclic? The idea of liberation seems to imply that time is linear, so I currently assume that there are at least two coexisting “times”: a cyclic time for the material cosmos, and a linear time for the souls. What do the Scriptures teach regarding this?

Comment: Read [Is Moksha a permanent state?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2457/277), also [What will happen when all atmans get moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10008/277) and [Does “Free Will” really exist, even if universe repeats itself in perfect pattern?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10911/277) may be of your interest.

Comment: The liberated ones are beyond Time. Time or Kaala, does not affect anything other than the material world. Once you are liberated you're free from the Entire Cycle. That's the whole point of Moksha.

Comment: The Entire Cycle includes Time Cycle, Life Cycle, Birth-&-Death Cycle etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moksha is a state that is beyond time.

> One who aspires to overcome the thick darkness of ignorance should
>   never seek contacts that are contrary to the fourfold end of life
>   (Dharma, Artha, Kama and Moksha). Of these four ends, Moksha alone is
>   accepted as the really stable value to be sought; **for the other three
>   are subject to the destructive force of Time.**

Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.22.34-35

Time is a property of the material world. It exerts its power only in the material world.

> Therefore, O dear one! Give up your infatuation born of ignorance,
>   which makes you feel worried, thinking – how will these helpless
>   people get without me? To think that one can save or protect another
>   while one’s own body, **subject to the power of time**, karma and Guna, is
>   decaying, is like a person in the grip of a python thinking of saving
>   another.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana I.13.44-45

There is thus no need to invoke a second time.