# When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?

Tags: avatars, brahma, yuga

When an day ends for Brahma there are no living beings and when a new day starts everything is recreated. My question is - does the same chain of events take place in the new day of Brahma?

For example, Shree Ram Avatar event that happened in this day (24th treta yug, Sita abduction, How Shree Ram get vanvaas etc) do the same events repeat on the next brahma day?

Events of Mahabharata (28th Dwapar yug how Shree Krishna tells bhagvad Gita to Arjun in the middle of the battlefield) does the same event happen in next day of Brahma?

Comment: That is the events that happens at the start of each yug, I do not mention what happens at the start i mention events that happen through out brahma's days.. as i mentioned in the question, Shree Ram avatar.. does that happen in each day of brahma. and if so are the events the same? and then Shree Krishna Avatar happens in each brahma day, than its events are the same? and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, exactly same events repeat**.
<sub>Also discussed in [Does "Free Will" really exist, even if universe repeats itself in perfect pattern?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10911/1049) and other related Qn-s.</sub>

> BG 8.17 - Knowing that thousand eras constitute a day of Brahman, [and] thousand eras complete a night, are the people who know day, [and] night.
>   BG 8.18 - On arrival of day, all manifestations originate from "Unmanifest"; On arrival of night they annihilate into [what is] known as "Unmanifest" only.
>   BG 8.19 - **This world of beings only happens again & again**; Annihilates upon arrival of night, [and] originates upon arrival of day.
>   BG 9.10 - Under "My" supervision, the Prakruti produces moving & non-moving [beings]; Due to this reason **the world revolves**

That means, whatever Shri Rama, Krishna, Shankara, Ganesha did during their live, exactly same things they will do in the next day of Brahma as well.
Not only them, you will be asking this same Qn and I will be writing this same answer.
This philosophy of [Eternal Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return#Indian_religions) is also known as "*kAla chakra*" by few.

---

On the rational side you may think like this:

1. The time is flowing continuously; Infinite time has passed before this moment and infinite time will pass after this moment
2. We are present in the current moment. How is that possible, if there is infinite time to be passed before current moment?
3. That means, there has to be a "timespan" (i.e. collection of finite events), which is repeating infinitely
4. With point 3, the time also becomes infinite (timespan x infinite) and we can also be present as current moment in the timespan
5. This "timespan" can be called the day of Brahma; The night of Brahma will be equally long, but nothingness pervades during that duration

That's why Shri Krishna told to Arjuna in the beginning of Gita:

> BG 2.12 - But certainly never was a time, when I did not exist, nor you, nor these rulers of men. And surely it is not that we all shall cease to exist after this.

Which means that all had existed in past cycles and will continue to exist in future cycles as well.

Comment: If everything repeats then that means, if someone has got moksha one time, Then he has to do struggle again to get moksha on next day of Brahma? We have to suffer from different yonies on every day of Brahman? If yes, then this is not good.

Comment: BG 2.12, States the reincarnation of everyone, however does not state the events being the same. They could be born as something else and that event cannot take place again in future? For example the event cannot take place if one has achieved moksha. Also the same theory cannot explain when Brahma is changed. Lord Hanuman has been given boon to be next Brahma does that mean Lord Hanuman will be meeting Bhim to destroy his ego?

Comment: @Rishabh, *"if someone has got moksha one time, Then he has to do struggle again"* -- there is **no again** for a person who attains Moksha. For example, Drona got Moksha during Mahabharata war. He might have gone through many births before it. In the next cycle, when Drona starts with his 1st birth, he won't remember anything of previous cycle. The matters, the actions, the thoughts -- all are same. Hence, from timespan (Brahma's day) perspective, all is done and dusted. Repetition of timespan - is to explain non-existent free will. Also refer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10744/1049

Comment: @chirag90, BG 2.12 is the byproduct of what has been stated in the earlier verses. Within 1 timespan, the Moksha is [permanent state](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8878/1049). Hence the discussion of next cycle become moot. The next cycle is exactly identical. A movie reel is printed which contains all the events. Regardless of how many times the movie is run, the events inside it don't change. Same thing is true for Brahma's cycles. Moreover, if all events are unique in the time, then there will be infinite time regress. Which is not possible.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64431/discussion-on-answer-by-iammilind-when-brahmas-day-ends-and-a-new-day-starts-do).

Comment: I disagree with @iammilind, checkout what [kakabhusandi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhusundi) says about [other yuga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11145/10405).